# Handle uncaught exception valueForUndefinedKey in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, runtime-error, nsunknownkeyexception

I have a third party library class whose source is not open to me. For example like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    let myProperty = 10
}
```

I can get `myProperty` value like this.

```
let test = MyClass().value(forKey: "myProperty")  // 10
```

I want to check whether `myProperty` exists in `MyClass`. Reason is I don't want my app to crash if the 3rd party class implementation changes in future.

For testing I've tried

```
guard let test = MyClass().value(forKey: "myProperty1") else { return }  // crash
```

---

```
if let test = MyClass().value(forKey: "myProperty1") { }  // crash
```

---

```
do {
    let test = try MyClass().value(forKey: "myProperty1")  // crash
} catch { }
```

In every way I get crash.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__lldb_expr_80.MyClass 0x608000223a00>
>   valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key myProperty1.'

Comment: Dont think there's anyway to prevent this, you must update your app or ask the lib's dev to change to more convenience way of accessing property

Comment: In Swift you cannot catch exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must find a better solution by talking to lib dev

You can use `Mirror reflection` and check its objects label

```
let myClass = Mirror(reflecting: MyClass())
for (_, attr) in myClass.children.enumerated() {
  if let propertyName = attr.label, propertyName == "myProperty"{
   print(propertyName, attr.value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When `valueForKey:` is invoked for an undefined key, [the runtime forwards the call](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1413457-valueforundefinedkey?language=objc) to `valueForUndefinedKey:`. The default implementation of the later simply raises `NSUndefinedKeyException`.

We can't catch the exception from Swift code, but we can override the method `valueForUndefinedKey:` in an extension and return some error:

```swift
extension NSObject {
    @objc
    func value(forUndefinedKey key: String) -> Any {
        NSError(domain: "Dynamic", code: 404, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Accessing undefined key: '\(key)'"])
    }
}
```